# Create an array from SimpleXMLElement response in php

Tags: php, arrays, xml, google-api

I am trying to import Google contacts in my code. I've successfully imported the contacts but my problem is that, I have to create an array of imported email addresses and I need to pass it to another page. But when I try to create an array, I get an array containing `SimpleXMLElement Object`. 
Here is my code:

oauth.php:

```
<?php
    $client_id='my-cient-id';
    $client_secret='my-client-secret';
    $redirect_uri='my-redirect-uri';
    $max_results = 100;

    $auth_code = $_GET["code"];

    function curl_file_get_contents($url)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        $contents = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $contents;
    }

    $fields=array(
        'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
        'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
        'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
        'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
        'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
        );
    $post = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $post = rtrim($post,'&');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $response =  json_decode($result);
    $accesstoken = $response->access_token;

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
    $xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
    if((strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Authorization required'))>0) && (strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Error '))>0)) //At times you get Authorization error from Google.
    {
        echo "<h2>OOPS !! Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>";
        exit();
    }
    echo "<h3>Email Addresses:</h3>";
    $xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
    $result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

    foreach ($result as $title) {
        $var=$title->attributes()->address;
        echo $var . "<br>";           //here imported contacts is listing properly
        $gc[]=array($var);          // creates my contacts array
    }
    print_r($gc);               //printing the created array

?>
```

My result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => email-address1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => email-address2 ) ) )
```

I need to get like this:

```
Array ( ([0] =>  email-address1 )  ( [1] => email-address2 ) )
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this. I'm stuck in this for many days. Thanks in advance

**Edit**

XML Response:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other [address] => emailaddress1 [primary] => true ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other [address] => emailaddress2 [primary] => true ) ) )
```

I have to separate the `emailaddress` from the response to a php array.!

**Edit 2**

here is `$xmlresponse`:

`email-id 2015-01-07T09:03:23.311Z profile-name email-id Contacts 2 1 100 http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/email-id/base/6cc9fe478fd427bb 2014-12-30T04:54:29.902Z`

`email-id` is the mail id from which contacts are imported.

Comment: can you post the xml response?

Answer (score 1):

In the first line of the final foreach loop you could try:

```
$var=(string)$title->attributes()->address;
```

or:

```
$var=(string)$title->attributes()->address[0];
```

Which is a bit of code from http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#116435

I think that the echo statement that lists the email addresses properly is implicitly calling the SimpleXMLElement::_toString(void) method (http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php). So to get the same result when creating the array you can coerce it to a string by putting (string) in front of the variable name.

EDIT:

You might also try this where you add to the array:

```
$gc[] = $var;
```

instead of

```
$gc[] = array($var);
```

Since the second way creates a new array object and adds $var to it then the assignment operator adds that entire array to $gc. Which would explain why the SimpleXMLObject was itself in an array. The first way ('$gc[] = $var;') will add a new element to the array $gc. Or you could initialise $gc before the foreach loop with:

```
$gc = array();
```

And then inside the foreach loop use:

```
array_push($gc, $var);
```

You will need to do both of the suggested changes to get the result you want, so:

```
foreach ($results as $title) {
    $var=(string)$title->attributes()->address;
    $gc[] = $var;
```

Comment: when I use `(string)` my emailaddresses inside the array is converted into single string ie, `emailaddress1emailaddress2`. But I need to get the emailaddresses separate

Comment: Can you post the output of "echo $xmlresponse"? Then people can work on the exact data structure. Replace any sensitive info.